# Image Break Up the Content

Tags: html, css

> **"Use images to break up the content."**

What do it means? What can I use code for that? html or css would do. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think this advice is telling you that the content of your page is too condensed (everything is clustered together) - or - the page you're to build should not be one big block of stuff. It sounds like they want you to add images in between blocks of content to spread things out and give space around things - to make things "flow".

Without knowing what the project is it's hard to answer a question like this.

Comment: Ah..i see.. project site...something like https://cdn.lynda.com/course/575947/575947-636307911984884050-16x9.jpg Hope it would be helpful after finding out what it is. Thank you again!

Comment: I don't have access to that url. I think I need a lynda account to view. Basically i think they want you to put your own images in so that all the content isn't clumped together. Sorry you got so many down votes. I think you asked the question wrong. You should give an example and a direct question about the example and not a question with a lot of ambiguity. Good luck!